# how can i use batch to call the program inside the if else statement

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

set /P user= Enter number: 
echo You have entered %user%

if %user%

(

start "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

)

else if %user%

(

start "C:\Program Files\google chrome\chrome.exe"

)

else

Pause
```

Comment: Explain your question a bit more, what errors do you get, what are you trying to achive.

Comment: code inside  IF ELSE statement do not get executed

Comment: acrtually i want to make a batch from which user can choose programs inside batch  e.g  if user choose 1 , firefox.exe is started; and if user chooses 2 chrome get executed and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with a Menu :

```bat
@Echo OFF
Mode 60,12 & color 9E
Title Start and open a Program
:MENU
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO     =====================================================
ECHO       PRESS 1, 2 OR 3 to select your task, or 4 to EXIT.
ECHO     =====================================================
ECHO.
ECHO       1 - Open Firefox
ECHO       2 - Open Chrome
ECHO       3 - Open Internet Explorer
ECHO       4 - EXIT
ECHO.
SET /P "user=Type 1, 2, 3, or 4 then press ENTER : "
IF "%user%"=="1" GOTO Firefox
IF "%user%"=="2" GOTO Chrome
IF "%user%"=="3" GOTO Internet Explorer
IF "%user%"=="4" GOTO EOF
GOTO MENU

:Firefox
start "" "Firefox.exe"
GOTO MENU
:Chrome
start "" "chrome.exe
GOTO MENU
:Internet Explorer
Start "" "iexplore.exe"
GOTO MENU
```

Comment: that works , thank you, can u please explain me about this code

Comment: @Lynus [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The code below lets the user to choose whether they want to open chrome or Firefox by choosing y for Firefox and n for chrome you can change the inputs to 1 or 2 or what ever you like.

Check if your paths are correct to the .exes

(Paths are different on my PC)

```
@echo off
set user=
set /P user=Type input y/n: %=%

pause


if "%user%" == "y" goto mozzila
if "%user%" == "n" goto chrome

:mozzila
cd C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\
firefox.exe
:chrome
cd C:\Program Files\google chrome\
chrome.exe


Pause
```

Comment: No sir its not working , if i input Y both program gets executed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the choice command too:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo 1. Firefox
Echo 2. Chrome
Echo 3. Internet Explorer
Choice /C 123 /M "Please make your choice"
If ErrorLevel 3 (Set "BEP=Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
) Else If ErrorLevel 2 (Set "BEP=Google Chrome\chrome.exe"
) Else Set "BEP=Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
If Exist "%ProgramFiles%\%BEP%" Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\%BEP%"
```

Comment: Please note that `if errorlevel 1` means `one or higher`, so if you enter `3`, all thee `set` commands gets executed, resulting in starting firefox *every time* no matter of what you enter. I suggest using `if %errorlevel% == ...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem

```
@echo on

set /P user=Enter number: 

echo You have entered %user%

IF /i "%user%" == "1" goto 1
IF /i "%user%" == "2" goto 2

:1
cd "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"
start firefox.exe
exit

:2
cd "C:\Program Files\google chrome"
start chrome.exe
exit
```

When the user enters 1 the first program is execute when 2 the second

Answer (score 0):

The correct format of "IF...ELSE..." is :

```
IF %user% (

    start "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

) ELSE ( 
    IF %user% (
    start "C:\Program Files\google chrome\chrome.exe"
    ) ELSE ( sth. )
)
```

the ELSE must follow the round bracket in the same line.